# Not found file after upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a problem with my function to upload files, i use SailsJS

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    const file = this.req.file('file')

    if (!file || file._files.length !== 1 ||
        !_.includes(sails.config.custom.uploadAllowedMimeTypes, file._files[0].stream.headers['content-type'])) {
      file.upload({ noop: true }) // prevent server from crash
      return exits.badRequest()
    }

    file.upload({
      maxBytes: sails.config.custom.uploadedFileMaxSize,
      dirname: sails.config.custom.uploadDirectory
    }, async (err, uploadedFiles) => {
      if (err) { return exits.error(err) }
      if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) { return exits.badRequest('No file was uploaded') }

      const baseUrl = sails.config.custom.baseUrl

      const fileId = path.basename(uploadedFiles[0].fd)
      console.log(fileId)

      const content = baseUrl + '/file/' + fileId
      const name = uploadedFiles[0].filename

      const attach = await Attachment.create({ content: content, name: name, fileID:fileId}).fetch()

      return this.res.ok(attach)

      // return exits.success({ url: `${baseUrl}/file/${fileId}` })
    })
  }
```

after performing this function correctly returns my data, just as it correctly saves files to me in the database

```
{
createdAt: 1584702842053,
updatedAt: 1584702842053,
id: 1,
name: "d16f3ed8-a290-477b-b39f-b90231254abf.pdf",
content: "http://localhost/file/e01c8cf9-90c8-40ce-9ba3-e4e46b39b4e1.pdf"
}
```

but when I click on content to open the file in the browser I get `Not found`
could anyone help?

Comment: I think the file was uploaded to `sails.config.custom.uploadDirectory`, could you check this folder?

Comment: @VanTho do you know what type of url should be there? for now I have `` localhost: 80 ''

Comment: Can you console log the output of `uploadedFiles[0].fd`? That shoud be the file uploaded url

Comment: @VanTho do you know what type of directory should be there? for now I have ```uploadDirectory: `${process.cwd()}/uploadedFiles`,```

Comment: ```C:\Users\...\Desktop\project_name\backend\uploadedFiles\f8250146-3379-4228-b6a7-ffc5eca9a5b5.pdf```

Comment: it's good destination

Comment: Yeah, can you try `http://localhost/uploadedFiles/e01c8cf9-90c8-40ce-9ba3-e4e46b39b4e1.pdf`? the uploaded folder is `uploadedFiles`, not `file`

Comment: still ```Not Found```

Comment: maybe my baseUrl must be diffrent

Comment: You can open the root directory by file exprore and see where the file is located. `http://localhost/uploadedFiles/e01c8cf9-90c8-40ce-9ba3-e4e46b39b4e1.pdf` is avaiable only when the root directory is poited to `C:\Users\...\Desktop\project_name\backend`

Comment: so, my full url must be: ```C:\Users\...\Desktop\project_name\backend\uploadedFiles\e01c8cf9-90c8-40ce-9ba3-e4e46b39b4e1.pdf```?

Comment: No, do you known where is the SailsJS public directory?

Comment: no, can you help me?

Comment: I haven't work with SailsJS, but the public directory shoud located at the same directory as package.json, you can list all of it, then go inside each folder to see which is the uploaded folder